# Views conditional filter

Tags: views

Is it possible for me to apply a filter in a view on a field only if that field is not empty? In other words if the field is empty the filter is not applied (and the row is shown), and if the field is not empty the filter is then applied and determines whether to show the row or not based on the field value.

My particular use case is a job expiry date. If no expiry date is entered I want the job to show, but if an expiry date is entered, then this determines if the job is displayed or not based on the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set up 2 filters:

1. Filter operating on date (as you described)
2. Filter "job expiry" field is empty

Then use the drop-button right of `Filter crieria`, go to `And/Or, Rearrange` **and change the operator for group to OR**

Let me know, if you need further assistance.